# Custom image angles in collage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a collage in `HTML5` canvas. However, I am finding difficulty in arranging the images in different angles. I want to arrange first pic at angle of PI/4 and the other one at angle -PI/70. Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHC3C/5/) with the problem.

```
    var pic1 = new Image();
    pic1.src = "http://www.fantom-xp.com/wallpapers/23/Windows_7_-_Swan.jpg";
    context.translate(170,170);
    context.rotate(Math.PI/8);
    pic1.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(pic1, 20, 20, 200, 200);
    }

    var pic2 = new Image();
    pic2.src = "http://www.redorbit.com/media/uploads/2004/10/38_ec8164eb3e4bddf76ef1b8eb564b9514.jpg";
    context.translate(100,10);
    context.rotate(-Math.PI/70);
    pic2.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(pic2, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A downvode without a comment cannot be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to rotate your images around their center points you need to use this drawImage:

```
context.drawImage(image, -image.width/2, -image.height/2).
```

That's because the translate point becomes the rotation point.

Here's a generic image rotation function:

```
function tiltedPicture(centerX,centerY,degreeAngle,image){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(centerX,centerY);
    ctx.rotate(degreeAngle*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.height/2);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code.

First of all, your first image couldn't be loaded. You will see it when you add:

```
pic1.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Error loading');
}
```

Next you should use `save` and `restore` methods. Read [here](http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/).

The problem is when you call twice `context.translate(170,170);` you will get th final translation at `x: 340, y: 340`. If you will combine more complex transformaions you could get result which is hard to predict. Fortunatelly there are methods save and restore. `Save` - saves current transformation state, and `Restore` - restores last saved state.

Usage in your case (for the first pic):

```
pic1.onload = function(){
    context.save();
    context.translate(170,170);
    context.rotate(Math.PI/2);
    context.drawImage(pic1, 20, 20, 200, 200);
    context.restore();
}
pic1.onerror = function() {
    console.log('error loading');
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fHC3C/6/).

Comment: Great, just draw images in load event handler and use `save` and `restore`. See my updated answer.